# How to test python code which imports libraries available only in production server

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to test a python module which is part of a windows service setup in a production server. However, the module I'm trying to test imports other python modules which, in turn, import libraries that only exist in a production server. Example below:

ModuleAlpha.py:

```
import A
import B

class X(object):
    pass
```

A.py:

```
import _winreg as reg
import pymqi
import CMQC

class Y(object):
    pass
```

MyTestModule.py:

```
from ModuleAlpha import X
```

I receive the following error when I try to run MyTestModule.py:

ImportError: No module named pymqi

I understand why I get the import error. My question is: is there a way to circumvent the module import that creates my problem?

Worth to mention that commenting out the use of pymqi in module A is not possible due to how the code is written.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't install the same packages in your test environment?

Comment: This seems to be begging for the answer "use mocking" but this is really too vague and, frankly, weird for a proper answer.

Comment: The last sentence appears to be missing some words.

Comment: Updated the last sentence. I can't install the package due to company policy, unfortunately. I actually did rewrite the code and was able to avoid the ImportError 

Answer (score 0):

So - there's two answers to this. The right answer and the wrong answer.

The right answer, is to sell your company on the benefits of having a pre-prod environment as similar as possible to prod. Having libraries in use in prod that aren't available in pre-prod is.... sub-optimal ("sub-optimal" is my way of being polite. The honest word is significantly less polite).

The wrong answer is to catch the ImportError exception. There are a couple of approaches you could take here.

```
try:
    import pymqi
    HAVE_PYMQI = True
except ImportError:
    HAVE_PYMQI = False

if HAVE_PYMQI:
    blah()
```

OR

```
try:
    import pymqi
except ImportError:
    import fakepymqi as pymqi
```

Obviously for the latter wrong solution, you'd need to implement fakepymqi yourself.